# fixed right navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to add a bootstrap fixed right navbar to my html page, but I found only fixed top / fixed bottom navbars examples.

It will be nice if someone can post a short source code for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `sidebar`. If true, then here is a [code](http://www.bootply.com/mL7j0aOINa) which helps you to go through it. If that is not the one you are looking for, please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fixed right side nav-bar

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div>     
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </div> 
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but this is a fixed top navbar and not side right navbar :(